# Manage Theme Editing using PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, themes

I have a theme in which there are numerous options, like:-

- Setting Theme Type among many available
- Setting Body Background Color & Image
- Setting Header & Footer Images
- Setting General Font Face, Size & Color
- Setting Text Area Background Color, and Font Face & Font Color
- Setting Form Area Background Color & Rounder Corners option
- Setting Form Element Background Color, and Font Face & Font Color
- Setting Link Default Color, Hover Color & Visited Color, with / without decoration
- Providing options to upload any number of Images to be used in the user's blog
- and many more...

Can anybody please provide any info as to how this can be done in a best possible way, using custom PHP & jQuery?
I'm also open to other ways around.

**EDIT:-**
I have got some 12 themes all worked out, along with their own style sheets defined & icon packs. I have also got them to load upon each of the customer's personal taste. **What I don't know is that how to manage the changes made to the customer's theme choice by that customer from his own account?** This has to take effect both the times :-

- when the customer is making / loading the changes from his account
- when the customer is viewing his account along with the changes

BTW, many many thanks for such a quick response, by two users & letting me know about my incomplete question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

    function template($file, $data = array())
    {
        ob_start();
        extract($data);
        include_once 'path/to/theme/folder/' . $file . '.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    // Assign values to the template file
    $values['theme_type'] = 'default';
    $values['bg_color'] = '#FFFFFF';
    $values['bg_image'] = 'path/to/bg/image.jpg';
    $values['font_face'] = 'Tahoma, Arial, Verdana';
    $values['font_size'] = '12px';
    $values['font_color'] = '#000000';
    // And so on...

    // Output template file
    echo template('theme_layout', $values);

?>
```

And the `theme_layout.php` file in `'path/to/theme/folder/theme_layout.php'` should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Theme Name</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: <?php echo $bg_color; ?>;
            background-image: url(<?php echo $bg_image; ?>);
            font-family: <?php echo $font_face; ?>;
            font-size: <?php echo $font_size; ?>;
            font-color: <?php echo $font_color; ?>;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    Theme type is: <?php echo $theme_type; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

You are right that was only the concept, here's what you have to do: Add new table in database `user_themes` for example and save all user related values there. For example user enters the admin page and sees a theme options like BG Color/Image, Font Name/Size/Color and enters his own values there... Form is submitted and values are saved in the database. Then during the theme display (where I assigned values to the template files) you get user entered theme options from database and assign as a theme values.

I really don't understand where jQuery should be used here, maybe in the form where user submits his options.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: very very nice concept provided by you. Many Many thanks. But please check the edited question once more & let me know how to control the customized changes by each of the customers.

Comment: Yes, I meant to control the user input process using jQuery. But many thanks again, for providing the way.

Answer (score 1):

Create various stylesheets (`.css`).  Each stylesheet represents a theme.  Change the `<link>` element's `href` attribute to match the path to the selected theme.

If you're allowing user-uploaded CSS files, make sure to sanitize the input, as IE has the ability to execute parts of a CSS file as if it were JavaScript, leading to possible XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks for such a valuable point mentioned. Sure I will do sanitize the o/p.